# Wordpress Load - Issue with Rewrite rules?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have begun to have some issues over the past week with the site not loading or not loading properly (mainly in Chrome and Firefox), as well as a time when the permalink structure reset to the WordPress default, and a couple of times when I've been logged out of the WordPress back-end when making edits.

My web host said that it it was most likely an error with a mis-configured re-write rule in the .htaccess file. I can't see anything wrong (but am not sure whether I would know if I saw it...)

The only times I find rewrite mentioned in htaccess are pasted below.

Do you think this is what the problem is, or something else?

Thanks

```
# BEGIN W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|sitemap(_index)?\.xml(\.gz)?|[a-z0-9_\-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js|htc|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The admin url for wordpress isn't based on Rewrite rules. If you're being randomly logged out while making edits either the session has been removed or has timed out.

As for permalink structure resetting, it would likely be one of:

- You or someone else with admin access has told wordpress to do so (intentionally or otherwise
- The .htaccess file in your base wordpress folder has been deleted
- The apache conf has been modified to ignore local htaccess / mod_rewrite rules

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by not loading properly, but if it were a htaccess problem I would think it would either work, or it wouldn't. Nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

> I have begun to have some issues over the past week with the site not
>   loading or not loading properly (mainly in Chrome and Firefox), as
>   well as a time when the permalink structure reset to the WordPress
>   default, and a couple of times when I've been logged out of the
>   WordPress back-end when making edits.

This sounds like a session timeout/cookie problem, and very unlikely related to your `.htaccess` rules.

In addition to firewall/proxies that may be in the middle of your browser and the server, such things can be caused by clock skews; try checking the time on your server and on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

[1]Clear you web cache.

If that doesn't help:

[2]Reset the htaccess file for your site. Reset the permalink settings.

If that doesn't help:

[3]Have you updated any plugins lately? Think about any changes that have been made recently to the backend of the site.

Hope this gives you some ideas.